# Write a function that takes an Integer list as input and adds 5 to each element of the list

Tags: list, haskell, map-function

I'm fairly new to Haskell and functional programming in general.
This seems like such a simple problem but I'm struggling with the syntax.
I want to take a list of ints as input, if it is null return a null list, and if it is not null then use the map function to add five to every element.

This is my code so far but it produces lots of errors. Any suggestions?

```
addFive :: [a] -> [a]
addFive []  = []
addFive a = map(+5)
```

Comment: lots of errors? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

You can use

`addFive = map (+5)`

or

`addFive a = map (+5) a`

As map works on empty list, explicit implementation for empty list is not required.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking along the right lines, but there are a couple of issues.

The code you have shown will complain about a type error. This is because the type of `map (+5)` is `[a] -> [a]`, but you want just `[a]`. To fix this you just need to change that line to

```
addFive a = map (+5) a
```

Look at the types and think about why this works.

You may also have tried this:

```
addFive :: [a] -> [a]
addFive []  = []
addFive = map(+5)
```

This gives you a different error because every version of a function like this needs to have the same number of arguments. Your null case takes one argument, so the other one has to take an argument too.

However you don't need the null case. `map` already has that built in. So what you actually need is

```
addFive :: [a] -> [a]
addFive = map (+5)
```

By the way, one stylistic point. In Haskell we use `a`, `b` etc for type variables, but `x`, `xs`, `y` etc for value variables. So the version above would be more idiomatic with

```
addFive xs = map (+5) xs
```